# Why can't I call a class created in another file. Maybe an Android Studio problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class

I have been having trouble with using a class that I created in another file. Both files are calling the same package and I've gone to multiple different places for help with this. I have a file called "Movement" that declares a "Movement" class that tells a robot the ways it can move. Now I have another file called "Robot" that tells the Robot where to move the robot and how to move along a playing field. When I call the Movement class it either confuses it or just flat out isn't understanding what I'm asking for, and when I try to build the code, it gives me errors. The weirdest thing is that it doesn't give me actual error messages in the code, but only in the build output of Android Studio. here are pictures of the errors that it gives me.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAWra.jpg

Movement.java:

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

public class Movement {
    public enum Directions {
        Right,
        Left,
        Forward,
        Backwards;
        public Directions InverseDirection() {
            switch (this) {
                case Forward:
                    return Directions.Backwards;
                case Backwards:
                    return Directions.Forward;
                case Left:
                    return Directions.Right;
                default:
                    return Directions.Left;
            }
        }
    }

    private int Distance;
    private int Correction;
    private double distanceTraveled = 0; //sets the distance traveled to 0

    private double LastDistance = 0;

    private double MaxPower;

    private double Slope;

    private double MinPower = 0.15;

    private Directions Direction;
    Movement(int Distance, int Correction, double MaxPower, Directions Direction) {
        this.Distance = Distance;
        this.Correction = Correction;
        this.MaxPower = MaxPower;
        this.Direction = Direction;
    }

    Movement(int Distance, int Correction, double MaxPower) {
        this.Distance = Distance;
        this.Correction = Correction;
        this.MaxPower = MaxPower;
    }

    int GetTotalDistance() {
        return Distance + Correction;
    }

    void setPowerSign(int sign) {
        this.MaxPower *= sign;
        this.MinPower *= sign;
    }
    Directions getDirection() {
        return Direction;
    }

    void setStartDistance(double StartDistance) {
        double totalNeededToTravel = StartDistance - this.GetTotalDistance();
        this.LastDistance = StartDistance;
        double TotalNeededCubed = totalNeededToTravel * totalNeededToTravel * totalNeededToTravel;
        this.Slope = -MaxPower / TotalNeededCubed; //gets the slope of the graph that is needed to make y = 0 when totalNeeded to travel is x

    }

    void UpdateDistanceTraveled(double NewDistance) {
        distanceTraveled += LastDistance - NewDistance;

        LastDistance = NewDistance;
    }

    double CalculatePower() {
        double distanceCubed = distanceTraveled * distanceTraveled * distanceTraveled;
        double power = (Slope * distanceCubed) + MaxPower; // the power is the x value in that position

        if (power > MaxPower) power = MaxPower;
        else if (power < -MaxPower) power = -MaxPower;

        else if (power < MinPower && power > 0) power = MinPower; //if the power is less than the min power level just set the power to the minpower level
        else if (power > MinPower && power < 0) power = -MinPower;

        return power;
    }

    void SetDirection (Directions Direction) {
        this.Direction = Direction;
    }
}
```

Robot.java:

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import android.graphics.Color;
import com.qualcomm.hardware.bosch.BNO055IMU;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.ColorSensor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DistanceSensor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.HardwareMap;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.Servo;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.AngleUnit;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.AxesOrder;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.AxesReference;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.DistanceUnit;
import org.firstinspires.ftc.robotcore.external.navigation.Orientation;

public abstract class Robot {
    final private double MaxPwr = 0.75;
    final private double NormPower = 0.40; //The normal power to give to motors to drive
    final private double MinPower = 0.20; //slowest it should do
    Movement MoveToZone = new Movement(7,8,NormPower);



    //declare motors
    private DcMotor FLM = null;
    private DcMotor FRM = null;
    private DcMotor BLM = null;
    private DcMotor BRM = null;

    //declare distance sensors
    private DistanceSensor RightDistanceSensor;
    private DistanceSensor LeftDistanceSensor;
    private DistanceSensor FrontDistanceSensor;
    private DistanceSensor BackDistanceSensor;

    //declare servos
    private Servo DragArm = null;

    private BNO055IMU imu; //declare imu

    private Orientation lastAngles = new Orientation(); //sets the last angle to whatever the robot last had. This is just to avoid errors

    private double globalAngle; //the number of degrees the robot has turned

    //declare color sensor
    private ColorSensor FloorCS = null;
    private ColorSensor RightCS = null;

    //servo positions for drag arm
    final private double DragArmDownPosition = 0.7;
    final private double DragArmRestPosition = 0.15;

    public abstract boolean AllowedToMove();
    public abstract void AddToTelemetry(String Tag, String Message);
    public abstract void UpdateTelemetry();
    public abstract void Sleep(int Time);

    public void Init(HardwareMap hardwareMap) {
        FLM  = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "FLM"); //get the motors from the config
        FRM  = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "FRM");
        BLM  = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "BLM");
        BRM  = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "BRM");
        FLM.setZeroPowerBehavior(DcMotor.ZeroPowerBehavior.BRAKE); //if we set the power to 0 we want the motors to stop
        FRM.setZeroPowerBehavior(DcMotor.ZeroPowerBehavior.BRAKE); //if we don't set it they will be in neutral and friction will slow it
        BLM.setZeroPowerBehavior(DcMotor.ZeroPowerBehavior.BRAKE);
        BRM.setZeroPowerBehavior(DcMotor.ZeroPowerBehavior.BRAKE);
        FRM.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE); //reverse the motors
        BLM.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE);

        FloorCS = hardwareMap.get(ColorSensor.class, "FloorCS"); //get color sensor
        FloorCS.enableLed(true);
        RightCS = hardwareMap.get(ColorSensor.class, "RightCS");
        RightCS.enableLed(true);
        //get drag arm
        DragArm = hardwareMap.servo.get("drag_arm");
        DragArm.setDirection(Servo.Direction.REVERSE);
        DragArm.setPosition(DragArmRestPosition);

        //get distance sensors
        RightDistanceSensor = hardwareMap.get(DistanceSensor.class, "RDS");
        LeftDistanceSensor = hardwareMap.get(DistanceSensor.class, "LDS");
        FrontDistanceSensor = hardwareMap.get(DistanceSensor.class, "FDS");
        BackDistanceSensor = hardwareMap.get(DistanceSensor.class, "BDS");

        imu = hardwareMap.get(BNO055IMU.class, "imu"); //gets the imu
        BNO055IMU.Parameters parameters = new BNO055IMU.Parameters(); //makes parameters for imu
        parameters.mode = BNO055IMU.SensorMode.IMU;
        parameters.angleUnit = BNO055IMU.AngleUnit.DEGREES;
        parameters.accelUnit = BNO055IMU.AccelUnit.METERS_PERSEC_PERSEC;
        parameters.loggingEnabled = false;
        imu.initialize(parameters); //initalizes the imu
        while (AllowedToMove() && !imu.isGyroCalibrated()) {
            if (!AllowedToMove()) return;
        }

        ResetAngle();
    }
    public Robot(boolean RightSide) {
    }

    void DropArm() {
        DragArm.setPosition(DragArmDownPosition);
        Sleep(500);
    }

    void RaiseArm() {
        DragArm.setPosition(DragArmRestPosition);
        Sleep(500);
    }

    /**
     * Runs until it gets close to wall
     * slowly gets slower
     */
    private boolean ShouldMove(boolean MovingTowards, double CurrentDistance, double TargetDistance) {
        if (MovingTowards) {
            return CurrentDistance > TargetDistance;
        } else {
            return CurrentDistance < TargetDistance;
        }
    }

    public void RushB(Movement Move) //moves with distance sensor. Slowly getting slower and slower
    {
        DistanceSensor TheDistanceSensor = null;

        switch (Move.getDirection()) {
            case Right:
                TheDistanceSensor = RightDistanceSensor;
                break;
            case Left:
                TheDistanceSensor = LeftDistanceSensor;
                break;
            case Forward:
                TheDistanceSensor = FrontDistanceSensor;
                break;
            case Backwards:
                TheDistanceSensor = BackDistanceSensor;
                break;
        }

        if (TheDistanceSensor == null) {
            return;
        }
        boolean MovingTowards = false;

        if (Move.GetTotalDistance() > TheDistanceSensor.getDistance(DistanceUnit.CM)) {
            Move.setPowerSign(-1);
            MovingTowards = false;
        }
        else {
            Move.setPowerSign(1);
            MovingTowards = true;
        }

        Move.setStartDistance(TheDistanceSensor.getDistance(DistanceUnit.CM));

        while (AllowedToMove() && ShouldMove(MovingTowards, TheDistanceSensor.getDistance(DistanceUnit.CM), Move.GetTotalDistance())) //while op mode is running and the distance to the wall is greater than the end distance
        {
            if (!AllowedToMove()) {
                StopRobot();
                return;
            }
            Move.UpdateDistanceTraveled(TheDistanceSensor.getDistance(DistanceUnit.CM)); //gets the current distance to the wall
            AddToTelemetry("Distance", Double.toString(TheDistanceSensor.getDistance(DistanceUnit.CM)));
            if (MovingTowards) AddToTelemetry("Direction", "True");
            else AddToTelemetry("Direction", "False");
            double power = Move.CalculatePower();

            switch (Move.getDirection()) {
                case Right:
                    Drive(0, -power, 0);
                    AddToTelemetry("Right", Double.toString(-power));
                    break;
                case Left:
                    Drive(0, power, 0);
                    AddToTelemetry("Left", Double.toString(power));
                    break;
                case Forward:
                    Drive(power, 0, 0); //moves the robot forward with whatever the power is
                    AddToTelemetry("Forward", Double.toString(power));
                    break;
                case Backwards:
                    Drive(-power,0,0);
                    AddToTelemetry("Backwards", Double.toString(-power));
            }

            UpdateTelemetry();
        }


    }


    public void DriveToTape(Movement.Directions Direction) {
        final double SCALE_FACTOR = 255; //For color sensor readings (make differences more obvious

        float hsvValues[] = {0F, 0F, 0F}; //store values

        final int RedThreshold = 50; //Anything below this number will be considered red
        final int BlueThreshold = 160; //Anything above this number will be considered blue

        Color.RGBToHSV((int) (FloorCS.red() * SCALE_FACTOR), //get readings before starting
                (int) (FloorCS.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                (int) (FloorCS.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                hsvValues);

        while (AllowedToMove() && hsvValues[0] > RedThreshold && hsvValues[0] < BlueThreshold) { //run until the driver presses stop or its on red or blue tape
            if (!AllowedToMove()) return;
            Color.RGBToHSV((int) (FloorCS.red() * SCALE_FACTOR), //check readings again
                    (int) (FloorCS.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                    (int) (FloorCS.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                    hsvValues);
            switch (Direction) {
                case Backwards:
                    Drive(-NormPower, 0, 0); //drive forward at the normal speed
                    break;
                case Forward:
                    Drive(0.3, 0, 0); //drive forward at the normal speed
                    break;
            }
        }
        //Driver pressed stop or we are on tape
    }

    void Drive(double forward, double sideways, double rotation) { //make a function to drive
        double correction = 0; //default correction
        if (rotation == 0) {
            if (forward != 0) {
                correction = CheckDirection(Math.abs(forward)); //if there isn't any rotation then use correction
            } else if (sideways != 0) {
                correction = CheckDirection(Math.abs(sideways)); //if there isn't any rotation then use correction
            }
        }

        FRM.setPower((forward + sideways + rotation) + correction);
        FLM.setPower((forward - sideways - rotation) - correction);
        BRM.setPower((forward - sideways + rotation) + correction);
        BLM.setPower((forward + sideways - rotation) - correction);
    }

    public void StopRobot() {  //stop the robot
        FRM.setPower(0); //set all motors to 0 power
        FLM.setPower(0);
        BRM.setPower(0);
        BLM.setPower(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get current cumulative angle rotation from last reset.
     *
     * @return Angle in degrees. + = left, - = right.
     */
    private double GetAngle()
    {
        Orientation angles = imu.getAngularOrientation(AxesReference.INTRINSIC, AxesOrder.ZYX, AngleUnit.DEGREES); //gets the angle

        double deltaAngle = angles.firstAngle - lastAngles.firstAngle; //deltaAngle is the current angle minus the last angle it got

        if (deltaAngle < -180) //switches it to use 0 to 360 instead of -180 to 180
            deltaAngle += 360;
        else if (deltaAngle > 180)
            deltaAngle -= 360;

        globalAngle += deltaAngle; //adds the deltaAngle to the globalAngle

        lastAngles = angles; //lastAngle is the anlges

        return globalAngle; //returns the amount turned
    }

    /**
     * Resets the cumulative angle tracking to zero.
     */
    private void ResetAngle() {
        lastAngles = imu.getAngularOrientation(AxesReference.INTRINSIC, AxesOrder.ZYX, AngleUnit.DEGREES); //sets lastAngles to current angles

        globalAngle = 0; //global angle is set to 0
    }

    /**
     * See if we are moving in a straight line and if not return a power correction value.
     * @return Power adjustment, + is adjust left - is adjust right.
     */
    private double CheckDirection(double Speed) {
        double correction;

        double angle = GetAngle();  //get the total amount the angle has changed since last reset

        if (angle == 0)
            correction = 0;             // no adjustment.
        else
            correction = -angle;        // reverse sign of angle for correction.

        double CorrectionSensitivity = 0.10 * Speed;

        correction = correction * CorrectionSensitivity;

        return correction;
    }
}
```

FYI this is for a robotics competition called FTC. The code is in a github located here: https://github.com/Wellington-Robotics-Team/Ultimate-Goal

Error Message 1:

```
C:\Users\silas\Desktop\FtcRobotController-master\FtcRobotController-master\TeamCode\src\main\java\org\firstinspires\ftc\teamcode\Robot.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    Movement MoveToZone = new Movement(7,8,NormPower);
    ^
  symbol:   class Movement
  location: class Robot
```

Error message 2:

```
C:\Users\silas\Desktop\FtcRobotController-master\FtcRobotController-master\TeamCode\src\main\java\org\firstinspires\ftc\teamcode\Robot.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
    public void RushB(Movement Move) //moves with distance sensor. Slowly getting slower and slower
                      ^
  symbol:   class Movement
  location: class Robot
```

Error 3:

```
C:\Users\silas\Desktop\FtcRobotController-master\FtcRobotController-master\TeamCode\src\main\java\org\firstinspires\ftc\teamcode\Robot.java:195: error: package Movement does not exist
    public void DriveToTape(Movement.Directions Direction) {
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster. Please don't use wrong tags. Similarly the problem is almost certainly not specific to Android Studio, but should have the Android tag.

Comment: Also, please don't post error messages as pictures, copy the text instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Made those changes but I still don't understand the errors or how to fix them.

Comment: Your file structure suggests that those files are in a package, but I don't see a `package` statement at the top.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I formatted the code block incorrectly, it was there, just hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I just declared movement in the same file that I am referencing it in. Solved the weird problems I was getting.